# Why can't I view all strips in Blender Sequence?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, movie-clip-editor

I'm trying to edit a video in blender but it's a hassle if I am only able to see two layers of strips at a time. No matter if I zoom out or drag the editor bigger, I only can view two layers of strip. I know there has to be a way to view all layers at one (audio, transform, video, speed control, color strip) I know you can make a meta strip but not interested in that! Thank you

Comment: Of course you can view more than 2 layers; see for example the image in the documentation (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/video_editing/sequencer/meta.html). Can you post a screenshot of your video sequencer window where you can only see those two layers? BTW, you are sure there are more?

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know you could tab into meta strips, but I figured it out!! All I did was press "A" and then "." To view all selected!! Thanks for the help!! Couldnt find anyone who asked this so thought I should put it out there!! P.S. this was also for just regular strips not Meta strips.